# A blank space appears next to scroll bar when popup resizes

Tags: css, scroll, microsoft-edge, responsive

I have a popup dialog with two panels. Both of them will resize and show scroll bars when window resizes. However, it seems the dialog's width automatically grows when window height reduces (I didn't specify any style related to width) and result in a blank space next to right panel's scroll bar:

blank space next to scroll bar
[image]

This blank space will automatically go away if I click another tab in the left panel and goes back:
blank space goes away when click other tab and goes back
[image]

This problem only happens in MS Edge. I checked with Chrome and Firefox, the popup's width will not change due to window height changes thus no such problem will happen.
Does anybody have any ideas about this? Thank you very much!

I cannot reproduce the code since it's generated from a gwt app. The html and css code is generally alike this:

```css
.wrapper {
 align-content: stretch;
  display: flex;
}

.menuPanel {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menuPanel > div {
  position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    min-width: 120px;
}

.mainPanel {
  min-width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    max-height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top:20px; background-color:grey;">
  <div style="height:auto">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="menuPanel">
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
        <div>Type</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainPanel">
        <div style="height: 800px">
        testtesttest
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE.. Is this for IE11 ??? From your images it looks like MS Edge on Windows 10 not Internet Explorer

Comment: Oh right. It's MS Edge not IE. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: We are gonna need a codepen or jsfiddle example so we can test this live to better help you. Looks like a CSS issue .. You might have to give the right column a min-width or width so it fits .. Thanks!

Comment: I added a code snippet, but I failed to reproduce the problem. The right column already has a min-width. Actually I can tell that it's the background wrapper's width that grows instead of the inside panel. Hope this provides more information. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow, added backgroud color and the problem is obviously in the code snippet result! Only MS edge shows an extra space next to the right scroll bar.

Comment: I see that you have `display:flex` on your `.wrapper` but you dont have `flex:auto` or other value for flex on your two `.mainPanel` div tags. Either add that for your flex box or you need to give `.mainPanel` a `width` of `50%` so both take up 100% of your `.wrapper` conatiner

Comment: Wow, it works by adding the flex: auto! Thank you very much!!!